# Google Closure Advanced | Object property not recognized | Dynamic Properties?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

**Actual Error Code**

> JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY

**Summary**

I get this error for the code listed and commented below.

I make the call like this.  `o_p.page` holds user input and one of the properties is indeed `tag`

```
Mo.AppBAdder.image_element = vDomBMAdd(o_p.page);
```

o_p.page is populated by calling the object which hold user input like this:

```
o_p.page = text_object.getArray();
```

Is there a way I can do this so Google Closure does not feel the property does not exist?

Setting options is O.K.  Also, I don't mind modifying the code a bit if needed.

The constructor for text reads in the user input like this:

```
Su.text = function (form_elements) {
    this.text_object = {};
    var key;
    for (key in form_elements) { //*u
        if (form_elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.text_object[form_elements[key].name] = form_elements[key].value;
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

**Snippet of Code**

```
function vDomBMAdd(bookmark_object) {
    var link_element = document.createElement('a'),
        image_element = document.createElement('img'),
        page_element = $a('#' + bookmark_object.tag + '_page'), // error here - inexistent property
```

**Reference**

Inexistent means same thing as nonexistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options: create an extern file that declares the 'tag' property or, perhaps more appropriately given how the property is defined, use a quoted property access:

```
bookmark_object['tag']
```

Both of these approaches allow you to access "external" properties and are both compatible with ADVANCED optimizations but using an extern file allows you to declare the expected type of the value held by the property and thus provides better type checking.

Comment: this now breaks jslint as it prefers the dot notation...static code analysis...hmmmm

Comment: jshint is a nice alternative to jslint as it lets you customize the warnings.  JsLint's author has no interest in supporting Closure Compiler's conventions