# Jshint vs. Closure | Dynamic Properties

Tags: javascript, jslint, google-closure

This is where I'm starting to find static code analysis odd.

Google Closure give me this error

```
// using dot notation
JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY:
```

when I use dot notation to access object properties that are dynamically created (i.e. there is no explicit creation of the property )

When I use bracket notation the error goes away but now jshint.com throws an error:

```
// using bracket notation
['tag'] is better written in dot notation.
```

I know that these warning/errors are only hints to write better code...but they contradict each other.

Here is the offending line:

```
vDomTagAdd(bookmark_object.tag);
```

**Related**

[Extern File Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254820/google-closure-advanced-object-property-not-recognized-dynamic-properties)

Comment: Personally, I'm with jsHint on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different warnings. Closure thinks that this property doesn't exists because it can't find the point where you create it. I assume that you can somehow tell Closure that this property is dynamic and you are certain it exists.

JSHint simply gives you a stylistic warning that it's better to use dot-notation unless you absolutely have to use brackets but it doesn't try to guess if your property is defined.